# Alert box on page loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I want my page to display a module or/and alert box onload (when opening a website), and it will disappear after a while like in 5 minutes.

Please have a look at this website to know what exactly I want: http://wazifa.af/

It has the facebook.com box on it. and instead of manually closing, I want it to automatically disappear in a second.

Answer (score 1):

it is very easy, just use this:

```
<div id="box"></div>

<script>
$(function() {
  $("#box").delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
</script>
```

[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/xq2Cu/9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%=dvMsg.ClientID%>').fadeOut(6000, function () {
            $(this).html(""); //reset label after fadeout
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $("#alertbox").fadeIn(); //-- First show the div onwindow load.
    setTimeout(function(){
    closeee(); //-- Auto hide the div after some time (6 millisecond ).
    }, 6000);
});

function closeee(){    
    $("#alertbox").fadeOut(); //-- Hide div 
}
```

[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/69WCm/3/)